# SpritKit Particle Design alpha's speed parameter

Tags: sprite-kit

Hi I am using spritekit's particle designer and overall it is very intuitive but in the alpha, scale and rotation section there is a speed parameter. I really have no clue as when I will use it. Like for instance in alpha. I give it a start value say 0.8 with a range of 0.2. Meaning that the alpha value of a particle will be in the range of 0.7 to 0.9. But then where does the speed parameter come into play?

On apples website here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/particleAlphaSpeed. it says Alpha Speed: The rate at which the alpha value of a particle changes per second. okay but change to what value at that speed? I never gave it a value to end. It makes it even more confusing when you know that the speed can have negative value.

Can someone please explain what is happening here. I looked around online for a while now and I am not getting answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the particle editor then you don't give particles  an ending value. If you have a particle at 0.2 alpha and the rate is 0.2 then eventually it will reach 1 alpha.  After a time the particle will disappear because of its lifetime.

If I have a particle with a 60 second lifetime but my alpha is 0.2 and my rate is -0.2 then the particle will disappear much faster than the defined lifetime.

The particle moves, fades, scales etc at a steady rate.

If you want to change that then you can programmatically define some sequences in your code.  particlealphasequence for example, will let you change alpha from 0 to 1 to 0.5 back to 0.  This is how you can define your own hard rules for how a particle progresses through time.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. ya the speed on alpha is negetive. So you are saying that the particle will fade faster. In that case if I increase the speed in rotation then over a period of time the particle will start rotating faster. right? Also in alpha if the speed value is positive the particle will be capped at alpha value 1.0? right? Thanks for taking the time and clarifying. :)

Comment: no it wont rotate faster over a period of time.  It will rotate at a constant rate. if my answer helped, do you mind clicking the checkmark next to it?  haha

Comment: If it doesnt rotate faster what does it doo if I increase it???. This is very lame of Apple. LOL

Well it always says that I dont have enough reputation so I dont bother most of the time as for evrything it seems I am not reputed enought.